# Cannot get kdump to dump a vmcore using crashkernel

Tags: kernel, 15.10, crash, amazon-ec2, apport

I'm trying to get kernel `crashdump` to work properly in Ubuntu 15.10 with the stock `4.2.0-22-generic` kernel. I have followed the methods described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/CrashdumpRecipe) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/kernel-crash-dump.html) precisely. But, when I manually trigger a crash via:

```
echo c | sudo tee /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

the system crashes, and reboots, but no crash output is saved in `/var/crash`.

As this is EC2, I don't have a read/write console--I can only get read-only console output, and I'm not seeing much useful output:

```
[  473.666303] sysrq: SysRq : Trigger a crash
[  473.668278] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
[  473.671624] IP: [<ffffffff814c79e6>] sysrq_handle_crash+0x16/0x20
[  473.672244] PGD 3e235c067 PUD 3e2351067 PMD 0
[  473.672244] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
[  473.672244] Modules linked in: isofs xt_CHECKSUM iptable_mangle ipt_MASQUERADE nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4 iptable_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_defrag_ipv4 nf_nat_ipv4 nf_nat nf_conntrack xt_tcpudp bridge stp llc iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables ppdev xen_fbfront intel_rapl fb_sys_fops iosf_mbi input_leds serio_raw parport_pc 8250_fintek i2c_piix4 parport mac_hid autofs4 crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul cirrus syscopyarea aesni_intel aes_x86_64 sysfillrect lrw sysimgblt gf128mul ttm glue_helper ablk_helper drm_kms_helper cryptd psmouse drm ixgbevf pata_acpi floppy
[  473.672244] CPU: 3 PID: 2814 Comm: bash Not tainted 4.2.0-22-generic #27-Ubuntu
[  473.672244] Hardware name: Xen HVM domU, BIOS 4.2.amazon 12/07/2015
[  473.672244] task: ffff8803d1d86e00 ti: ffff8803dc414000 task.ti: ffff8803dc414000
[  473.672244] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff814c79e6>]  [<ffffffff814c79e6>] sysrq_handle_crash+0x16/0x20
[  473.672244] RSP: 0018:ffff8803dc417e28  EFLAGS: 00010246
[  473.672244] RAX: 000000000000000f RBX: 0000000000000063 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  473.672244] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff8803ff2ce938 RDI: 0000000000000063
[  473.672244] RBP: ffff8803dc417e28 R08: 0000000000000002 R09: 000000000000024d
[  473.672244] R10: 000000000000a614 R11: 000000000000024d R12: 0000000000000004
[  473.672244] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffffff81cb48e0 R15: 0000000000000000
[  473.672244] FS:  00007fecdb3ca700(0000) GS:ffff8803ff2c0000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  473.672244] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  473.672244] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 00000003e234b000 CR4: 00000000001406e0
[  473.672244] Stack:
[  473.672244]  ffff8803dc417e58 ffffffff814c821a 0000000000000002 fffffffffffffffb
[  473.672244]  ffff8803dc417f18 0000000000000002 ffff8803dc417e78 ffffffff814c86a3
[  473.672244]  0000000000000002 ffff8803f816c900 ffff8803dc417e98 ffffffff81266aa2
[  473.672244] Call Trace:
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff814c821a>] __handle_sysrq+0xea/0x140
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff814c86a3>] write_sysrq_trigger+0x33/0x40
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff81266aa2>] proc_reg_write+0x42/0x70
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff811fca68>] __vfs_write+0x18/0x40
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff811fd3f6>] vfs_write+0xa6/0x1a0
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff810c3e21>] ? __raw_callee_save___pv_queued_spin_unlock+0x11/0x20
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff811fe0e5>] SyS_write+0x55/0xc0
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff8121b31f>] ? __close_fd+0x8f/0xb0
[  473.672244]  [<ffffffff817f02b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
[  473.672244] Code: 45 3b 7d 34 75 e5 4c 89 ef e8 f7 f7 ff ff eb db 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 c7 05 a8 74 a2 00 01 00 00 00 48 89 e5 0f ae f8 <c6> 04 25 00 00 00 00 01 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 53 8d
[  473.672244] RIP  [<ffffffff814c79e6>] sysrq_handle_crash+0x16/0x20
[  473.672244]  RSP <ffff8803dc417e28>
[  473.672244] CR2: 0000000000000000
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.2.0-22-generic (buildd@lcy01-22) (gcc version 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) ) #27-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 17 22:57:08 UTC 2015 (Ubuntu 4.2.0-22.27-generic 4.2.6)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic root=UUID=9bd55602-81dd-4868-8cfc-b7d63f8f8d7e ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 crashkernel=384M

...
[    3.021894] piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
...
[  OK  ] Started memcached daemon.
         Starting LSB: Execute the kexec -e command to reboot system...
...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Record successful boot for GRUB.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Execute the kexec -e command to reboot system.
...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Load kernel image with kexec.
ondemand.service
rc-local.service
grub-common.service
         Stopping LSB: Start NTP daemon...
apport.service
kexec.service
...
lxc.service
[  OK  ] Started LXC Container Initialization and Autoboot Code.
         Starting Container hypervisor based on LXC - boot time check...
[   34.181647] kdump-tools[773]: Starting kdump-tools:  * loaded kdump kernel
kdump-tools.service
[  OK  ] Started Kernel crash dump capture service.
[  OK  ] Started Container hypervisor based on LXC - boot time check.
```

And then the system is fully back online, with nothing in `/var/crash` except `.lock` and `kexec_cmd`.

I've tried `crashkernel=128M`, `crashkernel=256M`, `crashkernel=384M`, `512M`, `256@0`, `256@16M`, etc.

I even tried enabling `SSH` in `/etc/default/grub.d/kexec-tools.cfg`, with a machine I've verified I can access from this machine, with a manual `SSH_KEY` configured that exists, works, and has proper permissions set, but the remote machine doesn't show a connection attempt at all.

The output of `kdump-config show` looks proper:

```
DUMP_MODE:        kdump
USE_KDUMP:        1
KDUMP_SYSCTL:     kernel.panic_on_oops=1
KDUMP_COREDIR:    /var/crash
crashkernel addr: 0x2c000000
SSH:              ubuntu@10.xxx.xxx.xxx
SSH_KEY:          /root/.ssh/id_rsa
HOSTTAG:          ip
current state:    ready to kdump

kexec command:
  /sbin/kexec -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-22-generic root=UUID=9bd55602-81dd-4868-8cfc-b7d63f8f8d7e ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0 irqpoll maxcpus=1 nousb systemd.unit=kdump-tools.service" --initrd=/var/lib/kdump/initrd.img /var/lib/kdump/vmlinuz
```

However, when I manually trigger a crash via:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

The system reboots and no `vmcore` or `.crash` is ever written to `/var/crash` or to my remote SSH host. The SSH host never sees a login attempt. I see the trace output via `ec2-get-console-output -r <instance>`, and the system immediately reboots as shown above.

I'm very very stuck trying to debug it--everything seems correct, but no crash report.

Now, I'm not sure if this could possibly be related, but, `ifquery` is also crashing on startup, and there's no `.crash` report ever, and `apport` isn't aware that it crashed. I've yet to see `apport` ever actually create a `.crash` here. Could that possibly be what's going wrong with my crash dumps? Could anyone provide any insight into debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to this issue:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1421391

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - try disabling some of the most memory intensive modules that are unrelated to the kdump collection, I've seen many high-performance networking drivers to cause OOMs at work, also my home machine does have a high-end graphics, both examples lead to a lot of memory being loaded on kdump, leading to memory shortage, after all the reserved kdump memory is a tiny fraction of the installed RAM on the host as it is reserved on boot and unavailable afterwards.

So to identify which modules consume a lot of memory:

```
 $ lsmod | sort -nk2 -r | head
amdgpu               4116480  16
btrfs                1228800  2
kvm                   655360  0
nfsv4                 638976  2
drm                   487424  8 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,ttm
sunrpc                380928  9 nfsv4,auth_rpcgss,lockd,rpcsec_gss_krb5,nfs
aesni_intel           372736  0
fscache               368640  2 nfsv4,nfs
nfs                   299008  2 nfsv4
igb                   221184  0
```

In my case the amdgpu is on the top, but you could have all the modules I'm stumbling upon at work, like `ixgbe`, `i40e`, `mlx5_core`, etc.

To disable these just for the kdump kernel edit the `/etc/default/kdump-tools` and *uncomment* (perhaps copy, then uncomment) the `KDUMP_CMDLINE_APPEND`, then add the drivers to be blacklisted. Some might be in the kernel, some in the initrd, so to be sure, add each as `$driver_name.blacklist=1` and `rd.driver.blacklist=$driver_name` on this line, this is an example with `amdgpu` below:

```
[snip]
#KDUMP_CMDLINE_APPEND="reset_devices systemd.unit=kdump-tools-dump.service nr_cpus=1 irqpoll nousb ata_piix.prefer_ms_hyperv=0"
KDUMP_CMDLINE_APPEND="reset_devices systemd.unit=kdump-tools-dump.service nr_cpus=1 irqpoll nousb ata_piix.prefer_ms_hyperv=0 amdgpu.blacklist=1 rd.driver.blacklist=amdgpu"
[snip]
```

Then just reload the kdump-tools and ensure the new configuration is loaded:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart kdump-tools
$ kdump-config show
DUMP_MODE:        kdump
USE_KDUMP:        1
KDUMP_SYSCTL:     kernel.panic_on_oops=1
KDUMP_COREDIR:    /var/crash
crashkernel addr: 0x
   /var/lib/kdump/vmlinuz: symbolic link to /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-lowlatency
kdump initrd: 
   /var/lib/kdump/initrd.img: symbolic link to /var/lib/kdump/initrd.img-5.3.0-40-lowlatency
current state:    ready to kdump

kexec command:
  /sbin/kexec -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/@/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-lowlatency root=UUID=a745358b-a4e6-4a16-a347-5fa3d65e78a7 ro rootflags=subvol=@ quiet splash vt.handoff=1 reset_devices systemd.unit=kdump-tools-dump.service nr_cpus=1 irqpoll nousb ata_piix.prefer_ms_hyperv=0 amdgpu.blacklist=1 rd.driver.blacklist=amdgpu" --initrd=/var/lib/kdump/initrd.img /var/lib/kdump/vmlinuz
```

Then retry collecting.

Cheers,
T.